# Ошибка подключения к БД в ADO.NET

Tags: c#, sql-server, ado.net

```
        string connectionString = @"Data Source=.\Name;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True";
        var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
        try
        {
            connection.Open();

            Console.WriteLine(connection.State);
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            connection.Close();
            Console.WriteLine(connection.State);
        }
```

Получаю ошибку:  [image: введите сюда описание изображения]

SQL Server v2014, VS 2013
В чем проблема?

Comment: `Data Source=.\Name`. Выглядит подозрительно.

Comment: Вместо Name у меня стоит название состоящие из имени и фамилии :)

Comment: @TheOwl а это точно имя инстанса, а не компа например?

Comment: Переписал строку соединения так - @"Data Source=Name;Initial Catalog=Northwind;Integrated Security=True"
Все работает.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если при выполнении в PowerShell команды:

`[System.Data.Sql.SqlDataSourceEnumerator]::Instance.GetDataSources()`

поле `InstanceName` пустое значит у инстанса имя по умолчанию (`MSSQLSERVER`). Для подключения к нему вам нужно указать `Data Source=.\MSSQLSERVER;` либо просто `Data Source=.;`. Вместо `.` можно писать имя машины (что вы и сделали судя по последнему комментарию).

Answer (score 0):

А Вы уверены в правильности самой строки подключения? Подобная строка применяется при использовании Windows CE device.

Для подключения к MS SQL Server лучше написать так:

```
Server=myServerAddress;Database=myDataBase;Trusted_Connection=True;
```

Подробнее со строками подключения можно ознакомиться здесь - http://www.connectionstrings.com/sql-server-2012/